# How do I minify Bower components with Yeoman?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, bower

When I execute:

```
yeoman init angular
yeoman install https://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git
yeoman build
```

Then

```
ls dist/components/bower-angular/
```

returns

```
angular.js  component.json
```

While I expected angular.js to be minified and renamed to d10639ae.angular.js or something similar.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Minification in Yeoman is taken care of by the `usemin-handler`:

**GruntFile.js**

```
 // usemin handler should point to the file containing
    // the usemin blocks to be parsed
    'usemin-handler': {
      html: 'index.html'
    },
```

So open your `index.html`:

It should contain code like:

```
    <script src="scripts/vendor/angular.js"></script>

    <!-- build:js scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Everything between `build:js` and `endbuild` will be minified. So if you want to minify other libraries, place them between these two comment lines.

**Note:** there is an angular seed for Yeoman:

```
yeoman init angular
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you have multiple build/endbuild sections?

Comment: @msanford: sure. e.g. you can have a 'scripts.js' and a 'style.css' section.